# SQL query to split a comma separated column into many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, csv, many-to-many

I was given a 3Gb csv file that I need to import in SQL Server 2012.

I now have 5 million rows with data in a staging table that looks like this (simplified).

`Staging` table:

```
+-------------------+------------+---------------+------------+
|       Name        | Thumbnail  |     Tags      | Categories |
+-------------------+------------+---------------+------------+
| History           | thumb1.jpg | history,essay | history    |
| Nutricion Lecture | thumb2.jpg | food,essay    | health     |
+-------------------+------------+---------------+------------+
```

The question is about the `tags` and `categories` column in my staging table.

How can I transfer the information from my staging table to my actual table and also create an **unique record** for each tag and category -- *and* create the needed many-to-many relationships?

It would need to check each tag against the existing tags to either create a new record -or- fetch the `Id` of the existing tag.

`Programs`:

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id |  Program  | Thumbnail  |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 | History   | thumb1.jpg |
|  2 | Nutricion | thumb2.jpg |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

`Tags`:

```
+----+---------+
| Id |   Tag   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | history |
|  2 | essay   |
|  3 | food    |
+----+---------+
```

*(Categories table omitted because it looks the same as tags)*

The many-to-many relationships:

`Programs_Tags`:

```
+---------+-----+
| program | tag |
+---------+-----+
|       1 |   1 |
|       1 |   2 |
|       2 |   2 |
+---------+-----+
```

`Programs_Categories`:

```
+---------+----------+
| program | category |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |
|       2 |        2 |
+---------+----------+
```

I assume this is faster in pure SQL then it would be to write a tool for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is faster in SQL.  But, here is an approach.

First, create the five table that you need for this:

- Programs
- Tags
- Categories
- ProgramTags
- ProgramCategories

With the appropriate structures, including identity id columns.

Then load the data into programs.  This is easy, just an appropriate select.

Then create the `Tags` and `Categories` tables.  Here is how you would load the `Tags` table:

```
with cte as (
      select (case when tags like '%,%'
                   then left(tags, charindex(tags, ','))
                   else tags
              end) as tag,
             (case when tags like '%,%'
                   then substring(tags, charindex(tags, ',') + 1, len(tags))
              end) as resttags
      from staging
      where tags is not null and tags <> ''
      union all
      select (case when resttags like '%,%' then left(resttags, charindex(tags, ','))
                   else resttags
              end) as tag,
             (case when tags like '%,%'
                   then substring(resttags, charindex(resttags, ',') + 1, len(testtags))
              end) as resttags
      from cte
      where resttags is not NULL and resttags <> ''
     )
select distinct tags
from cte;
```

(Obviously this requires an `insert`).

Do the same for `Categories`.

Then load `ProgramTags` by using:

```
select p.ProgramId, t.TagId
from staging s join
     Programs p
     on s.<whatever> = p.<whatever> join
     Tags t
     on ','+s.tags+',' like '%,'+t.tag+',%';
```

The first join is to get the program id.  The second is to fetch the appropriate tags.  The performance will not be great, but it might be good enough for what you need to do.

Comment: Can't get it to work ---> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'tags'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'tags'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid column name 'testtags'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid column name 'testtags'.

Comment: @FrankieYale . . . I don't know what I was thinking, swapping the first to arguments to `substr()`.